# Folders included in the tar.gz, not in the wheel, setuptools build

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

The automatic discovery of `setuptools.build_meta` includes top-level folders into the tarball that shouldn't be included.

We were trying to build a [python package](https://gitlab.com/octopus-code/postopus) with `python3 -m build`. Our project has a [src-layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout) and we are using `setuptools` as the backend for the build. According to the documentation, the [automatic discovery](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#automatic-discovery) should figure out the project structure and build the tarball and the wheel accordingly.

For the wheel build it works as expected, i.e. only the files under `src/...` are included on the package. On the other hand, in the tarball build also top-level folders that are on the same hierarchical level as `src` are included. For example, the `tests` and the `docs` folder, which shouldn't be included. Interestingly, only a few files from the `docs` were included, not all of them.

We tried to explicitly exclude the `tests` and `docs` folder in the `pyproject.toml`, the `setup.cfg` and the `MANIFEST.in`, following the respective documentations, but none of them helped.

We configured the build backend in the `pyproject.toml` like so:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
...
```

We don't have a `setup.py` and our `setup.cfg` only contains `flake8` specifications.

We are using `setuptools-67.1.0`, we tried python versions 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. We tried it with an Ubuntu 20.04 and a Debian 11 running conda 3.8.13.

The tarball and the wheel can be seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/postopus/#files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full answer: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3883#issuecomment-1494308302

Summary:

- These [files](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist) are included by default in the sdist. The set of files included in a wheel is smaller. Thus, the behavior described above is expected.
- If you want to exclude e.g. the `tests` and the `docs` folder from the sdist, add these two lines to your [MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#manifest-in-commands):

```
prune tests
prune docs
```