# how to exclude "tests" folder from the wheel of a pyproject.toml managed lib?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I try my best to move from a `setup.py` managed lib to a pure `pyproject.toml` one.
I have the following folder structure:

```
tests
└── <files>
docs
└── <files>
sepal_ui
└── <files>
pyproject.toml
```

and in my `pyproject.toml` the following setup for file and packages discovery:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.2", "wheel"]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = false

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["sepal_ui*"]
exclude = ["docs*", "tests*"]
```

and in the produce wheel, I get the following:

```
tests
└── <files>
docs
└── <files>
sepal_ui
└── <files>
sepal_ui.egg-info
└── top-level.txt
```

looking at the top-level.txt, I see that only sepal_ui is included so my question is simple why do the extra "docs" and "tests" folder are still included even if they are not used? how to get rid of them ?

PS: I'm aware of the MANIFEST.in solution that I will accept if it's really the only one but I found it redundant to specify in 2 files.

Comment: that doesn't change anything but that's expected as both "docs" and "tests" are outside "sepal_ui" folder/package

Comment: Ooops, did not get the structure right. Anyway, I tried to reproduce it and I am getting a correct .whl file (checked with: unzip -l <WHEELFILE>). No docs, no tests.

Comment: I'm moving toward a solution, I had my egg-info/ and build/ folder polluting my local experiments. now the docs files are gone but the tests are very sticky. here is the PR if you want to have a look: https://github.com/12rambau/sepal_ui/pull/742

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fun fact, it was working from the start....

Small debugging workflow for the next person that does not want to spend hours for nothing.

## configuration of the pyproject.toml

the following configuration is the minimal to remove files from a `docs/` and `tests/` folders that are at the root of the repository. If you disseminated your tests in each modules, consider adding `*.tests*`:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.2", "wheel"]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = false

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["sepal_ui*"]
exclude = ["docs*", "tests*"]
```

## Clean environment

That was my mistake. Python is cahing information in the `build/` and `egg-info` folder. setuptools will use the lest of files stored in `egg-info/SOURCE.txt` so first step: **get rid of previous build files**.

Then simply run:

```
python -m build
```

## check both wheel and tar.gz

From the start I was checking only tar.gz thinking (naively) that `.whl` and `.tar.gz` were the same. It's not while the `tests` folder remains in the `tar.gz` file, it's absent from the wheel.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686298

Comment: related question about files in .tar.gz but not in wheel: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75364863

Comment: and possibly related issue: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3817

Comment: As per in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556996/setuptools-troubles-excluding-packages-including-data-files/11669299#11669299, because I had a `__init__.py` in my `tests/` and a non-test module, I needed to add `recursive-exclude tests *` to `MANIFEST.in` for anything under `tests` not be included.

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me for hatchling:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[tool.hatch.build]
exclude = [
  "/.*",
  "/docs",
  "/tests",
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This helped me to do exactly what I needed to do until our "packaging" standards change to keep only source files one folder. For now, we have everything under then main package folder, so this helped to isolate unneeded venv, test, docs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Flit:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["flit_core >=2,<4"]
build-backend = "flit_core.buildapi"

[tool.flit.sdist]
include = ["doc/"]
exclude = ["doc/*.html"]
```